# What's the difference between SQL Server Management Studio & SQL Operations Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Recently I came to know that Microsoft has launched a new application named as 'SQL operations Studio'. By going through its features page, I checked that all that features can also be provided by another existing Microsoft application named 'SQL Server Management Studio'.

Please let me know if there anything that can urge a developer to shift its focus from earlier to this new one.

'SQL Operations Studio' vs 'SQL Server Management Studio'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Windows, then probably no. The big "feature" of SQL Operations Studio is that it's cross-platform.

> SQL Operations Studio is a data management tool that enables you to work with SQL Server, Azure SQL DB and SQL DW from Windows, macOS and Linux.

https://github.com/Microsoft/sqlopsstudio

Apart from that, it's still in preview.

https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/sql/sql-operations-studio/download

I will also add a highly personal opinion:
*SOS is to SSMS what VS Code is to VS.*